# modular arithmetics - remainder

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I need to find the remainder of 
${1011}^{10}+{10}^{11}$
when divided by $101$.

According to [this](http://www.miniwebtool.com/modulo-calculator/?number1=1.1156078e%2B30&number2=101) website it is 55 but I fail to see how.

For 1011, we can write it as $1$ because $1011=10*101+1$ so ${1011}^{10}$ is $1$.

For ${10}^{11}$, I wrote the $11$ like $8+2+1$ or $2^3+2^1+2^0$

Then multiplying the results $10\cdot100\cdot1$ and taking the remainder of 101 I got 91.
$$1000=9\cdot101+91$$
So overall I have 92 for the answer, but the website says 55.
Was my method or understaning wrong or is there is a problem or limitation on large numbers in that calculator?

Also is there any website or mehtod to check myself with this kind of big numbers?

Comment: You did fine. I would do the $10^{11}$ part as follows:
$$10^2=100\equiv-1\pmod{101},$$
so
$$10^{11}=(10^2)^5\cdot10\equiv(-1)^5\cdot10=-10\equiv91\pmod{101}.$$
Looks like that website doesn't deliver.

Comment: Even simpler than what I did, thanks a lot for showing me this way and for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's the web-site's fault.  The input on [that page](http://www.miniwebtool.com/modulo-calculator/?number1=1.1156078e%2B30&number2=101) was 1.1156078e30.  You're not giving it the correct number $1011^{10} + 10^{11}$, which is 1115607835569227940375059334601, just the first $8$ decimal digits.  All the digits matter here!

Comment: I took whatever google gave as a result, with e+, so the mistake was indeed on my side, what did you use to get the full number?

Comment: Example how to calculate full number
http://codepad.org/5JsuDZ6z

Comment: Oh codepad.org is indeed a nice website, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

$$1011^{10}+10^{11}\equiv (101\times 10+1)^{10}+10\times 100^5\equiv(0\times10 +1)^{10}+10\times(-1)^5\equiv1-10\equiv92\mod101$$

Comment: sorry, -9 mod 101  is 92...

Comment: @kotomord Fair point, I was correcting it... Sorry it is hard to write from my smarphone.

Answer (score -1):

Try codepad.org

python works with the big number correctly

http://codepad.org/mZ9HW4zW

Comment: Or you could try [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1011^10+%2B+10^11+mod+101).

Comment: Thanks you both for the websites, it will be very helpful later on.

Comment: Provided that using a calculator for big numbers to solve a problem of modular arithmetics is very silly to begin with.